# Why does Visual Studio 2010's C# debugger continue instead of stepping over?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mstest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 2010 debugger skipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144880/visual-studio-2010-debugger-skipping)

If I break at a breakpoint in visual studio (C#), I can step over statements quite happily. Occasionally though, it ignores the step over and it's as though I'd hit continue instead.

It is not repeatable.. immediately re-running and breaking on the same point and stepping over will sometimes work fine, or will fail to step over on a different statement.

It may be my imagination, but the faster I step over things, the more reliable it seems. As though it's timing out on something.

My app is a single-threaded app debugging a method via MSTest.

**Update**

It seems to be more repeatable if I inspect things in the debugger, e.g. expand the 'this' reference in the locals window. It's not 100% repeatable though.

Comment: Are there any long running calls to other code or services? Could these calls be blocking, or have threads in their destination services that might be confusing the debugger?

Comment: Usually the complaint is that it steps over instead of stepping into when using the Step Into function which is controlled by Options -> Debugging -> General -> Step over properties and operators (Managed Only).

Comment: No long running calls. About the only complicated thing it is doing is appending data to a file.

Comment: _"but the faster I step over things, the more reliable it seems"_: I noticed the exact same thing!. ;p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known problem, it seems to strike particularly often in a unit test scenario.  The bug has been identified by the Debugger team as of October 1st, getting it to your machine is what tends to take a while.  The feedback article [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/663614/debugger-randomly-treats-step-into-and-step-over-as-run-to-completion), vote it up and keep an eye on it.  If this will be a hotfix instead of rolled into the next service pack then it will be [published here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Hotfix).

UPDATE: this was a regression from VS2008, a post-SP1 hotfix repaired it but the hotfix updates didn't make it into the VS2010 code base.  It was again fixed in VS2010 SP1.

Comment: The feedback article link is broken, it seems to have a [new URL](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/663614/debugger-randomly-treats-step-into-and-step-over-as-run-to-completion)

Comment: I'm using VS2010 SP1. It still occurs. It happens when I hover over a property to inspect its value. The IDE will momentarily lock up and then it will start responding again, but if I try to step over or into, it will continue to the end. In fact, I think it may have already continued to the end before I step over or into.

Comment: I'm still getting this error in VS 2015

Comment: The new VS2015 debugger has a very large number of bugs.  Avoid assuming this post has anything to do with it.